# How to show softkeyboard with numbers and signs on Android TV?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-tv, android-inputtype

Could anyone help me the way which combination of

> android:inputType

can directly show the softkeyboard with numbers and different digits in it. Take a look on that screenshot:
[needed softkeyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yl1v.png) That is what I'm looking for.

I have found combination of

> android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword"

which shows such keyboard: [found softkeyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyfhe.png).
But it's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no requirement for any Android device to have a soft keyboard with the particular set of options that you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Android TV's GBoard (Keyboard app) only supports email, password, text, and numeric input layouts. Unfortunately none of those is very close to what you're looking for. You can either implement a keyboard-like UI within your app to accomplish what you're looking for (substantial undertaking) or use the password layout and give instructions to the user, depending on your use case.